# Airodump-ng shows AP as OPN and WPA2 at the same time. What does it mean?

Tags: wifi, wpa2, aircrack-ng

The result of airodump-ng lists some AP's as **both** OPN and WPA2. How does the authentication work in that case?

```
12:34:56:78:AB:CD, 2011-09-09 15:29:47, 2022-10-21 16:09:05,  1, WPA2 OPN, CCMP, MGT, -75, DeLorean Free Wifi
```

Comment: I googled "wpa2 opn" and got this as the top hit https://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?topic=1543.0

Comment: So does this mean that WPS in enabled as mentioned here: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/pull/1868 ? Or is it just a bug?

Comment: I'm not sure how it can be both, unless it serves 2 networks

Answer (score 1):

This is from the bug report for the same (https://github.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/pull/1868)

> Open association is allowed (along with WPA
> and/or WPA2) to transfer unencrypted EAP packets between AP and
> client.

You can see the authentication value is MGT, indicating the authentication is handled elsewhere, not on the AP. The open part will be to send information to an authenticating device. Once authenticated, it will use WPA2.

You can read a bit more about it here:
https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007253447-Intro-to-Networking-AAA-802-1X-EAP-RADIUS